# show that $\frac{\Bbb{Q}[x]}{(2x^2+3x-5)}$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

show that $\frac{\Bbb{Q}[x]}{(2х²+3x-5)}$ is a field

factorize $(2x^{2}+3x-5)$ as a product of two polynomials in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$.

any hint is appreciated

Comment: 1) Please use [LaTeX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) for typesetting math. 2) "What have you tried?"

Comment: Your question is contradictory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an Euclidean Domain like $\Bbb{Q}[x]$, An ideal $I$ is maximal if and only if $\frac{\Bbb{Q}[x]}{I}$ is a field. And for PID's (An Euclidean Domain is automatically a PID) , an ideal(which is a principal ideal) is maximal if and only if it is generated by an irreducible element(a prime element as in PID's a prime are same as irreducibles) .

Here $2x^{2}+3x-5=2x^{2}-2x+5x-5=(2x+5)(x-1)$ . Hence the polynomial cannot be irreducible as it is a product of two distinct irreducible factors.

So $\frac{\Bbb{Q}[x]}{(2x^{2}+3x-5)}$ cannot be a field.

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial $2x²+3x-5$ has two rational roots, hence it is reducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, so the ideal it generates it's not even prime, hence $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(2x²+3x-5)$ is not even an integral domain.

Comment: if it's irreducible isn't that mean Q[x] is not a field?

Comment: @Anastasia Sorry, I've just edited the answer. Of course, I meant $\textbf{reducible}$ :)

Comment: @Anastasia $\Bbb Q[x]$ anyway is not a field.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I took for granted that she was referring to the quotient of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ by the ideal. What a chain of misprints!